# AOP logging and database queries

Tags: java, spring, logging, aop

I'm trying to log parameters in a query to the database by making use of AspectJ. The way I'm trying to do this is by jumping in during the calls to `java.sql.CallableStatement`, specifically the setters.

An example of what I have is this, where `String` is being set as a parameter in `CallableStatement` with the `parameterIndex`. This is essentially what I want to capture.

```
// Set the PL/SQL parameters
callableStatement.setString(1, applicationName);
```

In my Aspect class I have been experimenting (to no avail) with simply getting back 'anything' from ``CallableStatement` though ultimately I'd like to log all the setters within the class. The method I have is below.

```
@Around("call(* java.sql.CallableStatement.*))")
public void logGetters(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
LOGGER.info("QWERTY" + "Arguments: " + Arrays.toString(jp.getArgs()) + "Method: " + jp.getSignature().getName());
}
```

I do have other AOP methods working so the base setup is fine so it is my annotations and the body of the method where the error is. I'm pretty new to Spring AOP so some 'Advice' would be useful (forgive the pun)! Do I need a `@Pointcut` first or can I just revise the `@Around` to make it function as I desire or is my approach totally wrong?

Comment: are you using hibernate to make the stored proc call?

Comment: @dimitrisli I don't think so. It should be just JDBC.

Comment: The anonymous pointcut in your `@Around` advice should be fine, no need to declare a named `@Pointcut` first. But what I need in order to help you is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to understand more about package and class names, whether you want to intercept calls from your own code or from 3rd party code etc.